Issue with Pandas: Handling Dictionaries with Mixed Lists and Ranges
I'm working with a dictionary that contains a mix of lists and ranges (which are processed into lists), but when I try to convert it into a pandas DataFrame, I get the error:
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length.

I am also not able to query and find the values I want due to the same reason.
The below pasted code is a small section of my code and I am running into the above mentioned error. I also get IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.
ScaleX_Adjustment = {
    'X-Raw': [range(0, 34), list(range(34, 61)), range(61, 124), list(range(124, 179))],
    '1-8B': [+20, +20, +20, +20, +19, +18, +17, +17, +16, +15, +14, +13, +13, +12, +11, +10, +9, +9, +8, +7, +6, +5,
             +5, +4, +3, +2, +1, +1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -7, -7, -8,
             -8, -9, -9 - 9, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11, -12, -12, -13, -13, -13, -14, -14, -15, -15, -15, -16, -16,
             -17, -17, -17, -18, -18, -19, -19, -19, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20],
    'S-PP': [+10, +10, +10, +10, +10, +10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, -1,
             -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -6, -6,
             -6, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -9, -9, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11,
             -11, -11, -11, -11]
}
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF = pd.DataFrame(ScaleX_Adjustment)
ScaleX_1to8B = ScaleX_Adjustment_DF.loc[ScaleX_Adjustment_DF['X-Raw'] == ScaleX_Raw, '1-8B'].iloc[0]
ScaleX_StoPP = ScaleX_Adjustment_DF.loc[ScaleX_Adjustment_DF['X-Raw'] == ScaleX_Raw, 'S-PP'].iloc[0]

I need to retain the original structure of my dictionary (with lists and ranges) and find a solution for converting it into a DataFrame without encountering this error. Any suggestions or workarounds?
One thing I tried to do was expand all the lists and ranges and remove the structure I gave but that will be highly susceptible to low reliability and there should be a better workaround I feel.

Does X-raw always contain adjacent range (like in your example you could have 'X-Raw': range(0, 179) ? And why even the 2 other columns don't have the same number of elements?

X-Raw doesn't always have adjacent values. X-Raw is split into lists and ranges as you can see, in the sample I have given. range(0, 34) of X-Raw will give +20 and +10 accordingly but 35 X-Raw will give a different value.

Thank you all for helping, I solved the problem!

Good. You may want to accept/upvote the answer(s) you found useful or add your answer if none of the answers below solved the question.

Here I have tried to flatten the ScaleX_Adjustment dictionary into a format where each individual value in the lists and ranges of X-Raw gets its own row. Additionally, the values in 1-8B and S-PP should be repeated for each of the corresponding rows created from the 'X-Raw' lists/ranges.
You can try below approach:
import pandas as pd

ScaleX_Adjustment = {
    'X-Raw': [range(0, 34), list(range(34, 61)), range(61, 124), list(range(124, 179))],
    '1-8B': [+20, +20, +20, +20, +19, +18, +17, +17, +16, +15, +14, +13, +13, +12, +11, +10, +9, +9, +8, +7, +6, +5,
             +5, +4, +3, +2, +1, +1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -7, -7, -8,
             -8, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11, -12, -12, -13, -13, -13, -14, -14, -15, -15, -15, -16, -16,
             -17, -17, -17, -18, -18, -19, -19, -19, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20],
    'S-PP': [+10, +10, +10, +10, +10, +10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, -1,
             -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -6, -6,
             -6, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -9, -9, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11,
             -11, -11, -11, -11]
}

# Flatten the dictionary by expanding the 'X-Raw' ranges and lists into individual rows
expanded_rows = []
for i, row in enumerate(zip(*ScaleX_Adjustment.values())):
    # Each element in row corresponds to the columns 'X-Raw', '1-8B', and 'S-PP'
    x_raw = row[0]  
    for x_value in x_raw:
        expanded_rows.append({
            'X-Raw': x_value,
            '1-8B': row[1],  # Keep '1-8B' value consistent across the expanded rows
            'S-PP': row[2]   # Keep 'S-PP' value consistent across the expanded rows
        })


expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_rows)

# Query the DataFrame
ScaleX_Raw = 34  # Example value for query
ScaleX_1to8B = expanded_df.loc[expanded_df['X-Raw'] == ScaleX_Raw, '1-8B'].iloc[0]
ScaleX_StoPP = expanded_df.loc[expanded_df['X-Raw'] == ScaleX_Raw, 'S-PP'].iloc[0]

# Output the expanded DataFrame and the queried values
print(expanded_df)
print(f"ScaleX_1to8B: {ScaleX_1to8B}, ScaleX_StoPP: {ScaleX_StoPP}")

https://www.online-python.com/wIOpTrBch6

Thank you for taking your time to respond. The code is not giving the desired output. It is creating a dataframe with same values across:
X-Raw  1-8B  S-PP
0        0    20    10
1        1    20    10
2        2    20    10
3        3    20    10
4        4    20    10
..     ...   ...   ...
174    174    20    10
175    175    20    10
176    176    20    10
177    177    20    10
178    178    20    10

Sorry to hear that. I am sharing here another approach. Please have a look https://www.online-python.com/5KZoNhwqgm . If it's not the output you are looking for can you please share your desired output. I am also not an python expert rather trying.

I am postin another answer below, in case I misunderstood the assignment. An interpretation to your problem, tell me if I am wrong, is that the measurements come in groups of 4, so perhaps you actually need a table like the following one:
    X_raw         1-8B  S-PP
0   range(0, 34)    20  10
1   range(34, 61)   20  10
2   range(61, 124)  20  10
3   range(124, 179) 20  10
4   range(0, 34)    19  10
5   range(34, 61)   18  10
6   range(61, 124)  17  9
7   range(124, 179) 17  9
8   range(0, 34)    16  9

In this case, you need to repeat the 4 ranges of X 21 times to match the length of the other columns
ScaleX_Adjustment = {
    'X_raw': [range(0, 34), range(34, 61), range(61, 124), range(124, 179)] *21,
    '1-8B': [+20, +20, +20, +20, +19, +18, +17, +17, +16, +15, +14, +13, +13, +12, +11, +10, +9, +9, +8, +7, +6, +5,
             +5, +4, +3, +2, +1, +1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -7, -7, -8,
             -8, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11, -12, -12, -13, -13, -13, -14, -14, -15, -15, -15, -16, -16,
             -17, -17, -17, -18, -18, -19, -19, -19, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20],
    'S-PP': [+10, +10, +10, +10, +10, +10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, -1,
             -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -6, -6,
             -6, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -9, -9, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11,
             -11, -11, -11, -11]
}
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF = pd.DataFrame(ScaleX_Adjustment)

Then you can filter by X:
def get_range(x):
    for r in [range(0, 34), range(34, 61), range(61, 124), range(124, 179)]:
        if x in r:
            return r

ScaleX_Adjustment_DF[ScaleX_Adjustment_DF["X_raw"]==get_range(50)]


Another interpretation
Since I am not sure I understand completely what you are asking, this is another guess:

there are 179 possible values of X
these X come in 4 possible ranges (from 0 to 33, from 33 to 60,...)
independently of X, we have 84 possible 1to8B adjustments
these 1to8B adjustments correspond one-to-one to 84 StoPP adjustments.

Then, I would first create a table with 84 entries for the adjustments
import pandas as pd
ScaleX_Adjustment_Only = {
    '1-8B': [+20, +20, +20, +20, +19, +18, +17, +17, +16, +15, +14, +13, +13, +12, +11, +10, +9, +9, +8, +7, +6, +5,
             +5, +4, +3, +2, +1, +1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -7, -7, -8,
             -8, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11, -12, -12, -13, -13, -13, -14, -14, -15, -15, -15, -16, -16,
             -17, -17, -17, -18, -18, -19, -19, -19, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20],
    'S-PP': [+10, +10, +10, +10, +10, +10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, -1,
             -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -6, -6, -6, -6,
             -6, -7, -7, -7, -7, -7, -8, -8, -8, -8, -8, -9, -9, -9, -9, -9, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -11, -11, -11,
             -11, -11, -11, -11]
}
ScaleX_Adjustment_Only_DF = pd.DataFrame(ScaleX_Adjustment_Only)

Then I would create a separate table with the X and their ranges
def get_range(x):
    for r in [range(0, 34), range(34, 61), range(61, 124), range(124, 179)]:
        if x in r:
            return r
ScaleX_Ranges = {
    'X-Raw': list(range(0,179)),
    'X-Range': [get_range(x) for x in range(0,179)]
}
scaleX_Ranges_DF = pd.DataFrame(ScaleX_Ranges)

Finally, I would cross merge the two tables into a common table so that for each X you have 84 possible adjustments.
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF = pd.merge(scaleX_Ranges_DF,ScaleX_Adjustment_Only_DF, how = "cross")

It should create a dataframe like the following one:
   X-Raw    X-Range   1-8B  S-PP
0   0   range(0, 34)    20  10
1   0   range(0, 34)    20  10
2   0   range(0, 34)    20  10
3   0   range(0, 34)    20  10
4   0   range(0, 34)    19  10


I finally made it!
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF = pd.DataFrame({key:[[]] for key in ScaleX_Adjustment.keys()})

for key in ScaleX_Adjustment.keys():
    ScaleX_Adjustment_DF.loc[0, key] = ScaleX_Adjustment[key]

Output
                                               X-Raw  ...                                               S-PP
0  [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13...  ...  [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, ...

[1 rows x 3 columns]

However pandas converts lists into series, therefore you have to extract packed data with values property as shown below.
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF['X-Raw'].values[0]
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF['1-8B'].values[0]
ScaleX_Adjustment_DF['S-PP'].values[0]


Thank you for taking your time to respond. But with this I see an index error and the lists are not expanding and each item in the list is supposed to go into a row and I am not able to do that too.
I ran to an index error even with the post you have linked to. Is there any other work around?

The idea here is to expand the dictionary to have the same number of elements in all 3 columns/keys and then create the dataframe.
Based on the image given, I assumed that in X-Raw, there are only "range(...)" or "list(range(...))" and that if it is "range(...)" there is a unique corresponding value in 1-8B/S-PP.
As I mentioned in the comment the columns 2 and 3 didn't have the same length. Actually in "1-8B", one "," was missing between 2 "9" !
newDict = {'X-Raw':[], '1-8B':[], 'S-PP':[]}
rowN = 0  

for x in ScaleX_Adjustment["X-Raw"]:
    R = range(len(x))
    if type(x) != list:
        newDict['X-Raw'] += [i for i in x]
        newDict['1-8B'] += [ScaleX_Adjustment["1-8B"][rowN] for i in R]
        newDict['S-PP'] += [ScaleX_Adjustment["S-PP"][rowN] for i in R]
        rowN += 1
    else:
        newDict['X-Raw'] += [i for i in x]
        newDict['1-8B'] += [ScaleX_Adjustment["1-8B"][rowN + i] for i in R] 
        newDict['S-PP'] += [ScaleX_Adjustment["S-PP"][rowN + i] for i in R] 
        rowN += len(x)

ScaleX_Adjustment_DF = pd.DataFrame(newDict)
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', None):
    display(ScaleX_Adjustment_DF.T)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178
X-Raw   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178
1-8B    20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  19  18  17  17  16  15  14  13  13  12  11  10  9   9   8   7   6   5   5   4   3   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -2  -2  -3  -3  -3  -4  -4  -5  -5  -5  -6  -6  -7  -7  -7  -8  -8  -9  -9  -9  -10 -10 -11 -11 -11 -12 -12 -13 -13 -13 -14 -14 -15 -15 -15 -16 -16 -17 -17 -17 -18 -18 -19 -19 -19 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20 -20
S-PP    10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  9   9   9   8   8   7   7   7   6   6   5   5   5   4   4   3   3   3   2   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -2  -2  -2  -2  -2  -3  -3  -3  -3  -3  -4  -4  -4  -4  -4  -5  -5  -5  -5  -5  -6  -6  -6  -6  -6  -7  -7  -7  -7  -7  -8  -8  -8  -8  -8  -9  -9  -9  -9  -9  -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -11 -11 -11 -11 -11 -11 -11

